# Efficiently counting grouped elements in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to create a new column that will give me the counts when a particular group occurs. I am doing something like the following ...

```
import pandas as pd 

table = '''A B C
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 4
2 1 3
2 1 5'''

df = pd.DataFrame([t.split(' ') for t in table.split('\n')[1:]], 
        columns=table.split('\n')[0].split(' '))

def appendCnt(df, factors):
    f = 'counts-'+ '-'.join(factors)
    df[f] = 0
    for k, v in df.groupby(factors):
        df[f].ix[v.index] = len(v)
    return df

factors = ['A', 'B']
print appendCnt(df, factors)
```

When I run this code, it is unacceptably slow:

```
In [7]: run test
   A  B  C  counts-A-B
0  1  1  1           3
1  1  1  2           3
2  1  1  4           3
3  2  1  3           2
4  2  1  5           2

In [8]: %timeit for _ in xrange(5): appendCnt1(df, factors)
1 loops, best of 3: 225 ms per loop
```

It appears that most of the time is spent in writing out the new data within the table. Is there perhaps a faster way of accomplishing this? I feel that there must be a way of doing this faster because this is really such a fundamental operation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want, you can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
df['counts-'+ '-'.join(factors)] = df.groupby(factors).transform("count")

df
Out[6]: 
   A  B  C  counts-A-B
0  1  1  1           3
1  1  1  2           3
2  1  1  4           3
3  2  1  3           2
4  2  1  5           2
```

Comment: I thought so but I was about to do the tests. You're welcome.

Comment: Very nice solution. :)

Comment: It appears that the solution will fail if we have more than 3 columns, but a simple change to `df.groupby(factors).transform("count").ix[:,0]` will solve the problem that I am looking to solve. Thanks for showing me the `transform` function.

Comment: Ah yes, the functions on groupby objects are applied to all nongrouped columns where possible. Another alternative is to take just one column from the groupby object: ` df.groupby(factors)["C"].transform("count")`. This one maybe more efficient as it does the selection first and then applies the function.